# System program problem detected from apport: should i worry about it?

Tags: apport

I'm quite new to Ubuntu, I've installed 18.04 on my laptop 2 weeks ago. However sometimes, like every couple of days, I get the report "System program problem detected" from apport. I know I can disable it and there are other similar questions, but I'd just like to know if I have to worry about it or not. I post the apport log I got today, but it is always the same log:

> ERROR: apport (pid 4610) Sun Mar  1 11:47:38 2020: called for pid 1000, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 4610) Sun Mar  1 11:47:38 2020: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-shell (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-shell")
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 4610) Sun Mar  1 11:47:38 2020: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 4610) Sun Mar  1 11:52:53 2020: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 4644) Sun Mar  1 11:52:53 2020: Unhandled exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/share/apport/apport", line 532, in 
>       get_pid_info(pid)
>
> File "/usr/share/apport/apport", line 78, in get_pid_info
>       proc_pid_fd = os.open('/proc/%s' % pid, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_PATH | os.O_DIRECTORY)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/1038'
>   ERROR: apport (pid 4644) Sun Mar  1 11:52:53 2020: pid: 4644, uid: 0, gid: 0, euid: 0, egid: 0
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 4644) Sun Mar  1 11:52:53 2020: environment: environ({})

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: As requested by heynnema:

```
ls -al /var/crash:
total 20516
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie     4096 mar  2 12:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root         4096 ago  5  2019 ..
-rw-r-----  1 gdm  whoopsie 20997898 mar  2 12:43 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions:
impossibile accedere a '/home/addari/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': File o directory non esistente
```

Since It is in italian, It means that it cannot access the folder because it does not exist.

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            11G        1,8G        7,5G        292M        2,2G        9,1G
Swap:          9,3G          0B        9,3G
```

(Today It happened again, always the same log apart from pid number and date/hour)

EDIT 2:

```
ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 ago  5  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 feb 20 12:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 ago  5  2019 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 ago  5  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com


ls -al ~/Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  5 addari addari 4096 mar  1 14:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 addari addari 4096 mar  2 17:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 addari addari 4096 feb 24 19:05 01tutorial
drwxr-xr-x 10 addari addari 4096 mar  2 12:27 1M_pre_ms_to_wd
-rw-r--r--  1 addari addari  370 mar  1 14:56 note_cartelle
drwxr-xr-x 10 addari addari 4096 mar  2 12:16 V2_1M_pre_ms_to_wd

sudo lshw -C memory: 
*-cache:0                 
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 2
   slot: L1 Cache
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 64KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
   configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 3
   slot: L1 Cache
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 64KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
   configuration: level=1
 *-cache:2
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 4
   slot: L2 Cache
   size: 512KiB
   capacity: 512KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=2
  *-cache:3
   description: L3 cache
   physical id: 5
   slot: L3 Cache
   size: 3MiB
   capacity: 3MiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=3
  *-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 7
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 12GiB
     *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
      product: ATF51264HZ-2G3B2   2
      vendor: 4154
      physical id: 0
      serial: 32363448
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
      size: 4GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
      description: [empty]
      physical id: 1
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
      description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
      product: CT8G4SFS824A.C8FDD1
      vendor: 859B
      physical id: 2
      serial: E1238D7A
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
      description: [empty]
      physical id: 3
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-firmware
   description: BIOS
   vendor: LENOVO
   physical id: d
   version: 1KCN28WW
   date: 11/15/2016
   size: 128KiB
   capacity: 6080KiB
   capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video pc98 acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
   description: Memory controller
   product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
   version: 21
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d1224000-d1227fff
```

EDIT 3: Something new happened, after leaving the .crash file

> ERROR: apport (pid 14161) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: called for pid 10465, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14161) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-shell (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-shell")
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14161) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14161) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14186) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: called for pid 10474, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615, dump mode 1
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14186) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14186) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: executable: /usr/bin/Xwayland (command line "/usr/bin/Xwayland :1024 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6")
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14186) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14186) Mon Mar  2 18:22:06 2020: debug: session gdbus call:
>
> ERROR: apport (pid 14186) Mon Mar  2 18:22:09 2020: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_Xwayland.121.crash

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105138/discussion-on-question-by-f-addari-system-program-problem-detected-from-apport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wayland**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

Change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

To:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`.

`reboot` # reboot the computer

---

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

---

**BIOS**

**Note**: Perform backups prior to updating your BIOS.

You have an older BIOS version 1KCN28WW. The current BIOS is version 1KCN49WW.

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

It can be downloaded at https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/by/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v110-15isk/downloads/ds119358 and will probably require Windows to install (although some computers allow you to update the BIOS from the existing BIOS).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will try your solution as soon as possible.
(Yes It is the correct page for my model)

Comment: @F.Addari The "accept" checkmark should only be checked after you've tried my answer, and it's solved the problem. You may wish to uncheck it for now, and come back later :-)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry about that I'm new here.. Something new happened however (I edited the question)

Comment: @F.Addari yes, that crash file is "ignoring implausibly big core limit" huge. Was this AFTER you've made any of my changes? Go ahead and manually delete that crash log again.

Comment: I still did nothing.

Comment: @F.Addari Go ahead and do the Wayland part now, and the rest as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the suggestion that you "should not worry about it."  Begin by applying all now-available software updates for your computer.

It looks to me like this bug is *in `apport` itself.*  (See "https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport")  It looks like it's trying to find a `/proc` entry for a process #1038 which is already gone, and it's not handling that graciously.

If a software-update and reboot does not resolve the problem, you should probably open a bug-report ticket on the issue.

Comment: We agree that the user "should" worry about it. This /proc thing may be because the user was manually deleting files from /var/crash.

Comment: I've run sudo apt update and upgrade, restarted and it reports again.. If i manually delete the files from /var/crash then the report comes back after a while or the day after